# Getting error message: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, module, lowercase

I have the problem, that I am trying to run a function which has as input an array of strings and before making some if-statement I am lowering the strings. somehow i am receiving the error message

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

It is not clear for me why do I receive it. The funny part is, If I have both in one script it works. If I source the function out and load it into another script it does not work. The code looks like the following:

```
def Calc(String_Array1, String_Array2):
    String_Array1 = String_Array1.lower()
    String_Array2 = String_Array2.lower()

    if String_Array1 == "a":
        print(String_Array1)  
    elif String_Array2 == "b":
        print(String_Array2)
    else:
        raise Exception("Something went wrong")


    return 0
```

I am running then my own module like the following

```
import helper_module as hm

String_Array1 = ["A"]    
String_Array2 = ["B"]

test = hm.CalcFXFwdCurve(String_Array1,String_Array2)

print(test)
```

Comment: `lower()` method is applicable to python string objects not list objects.

Comment: Not sure how it works in your other script but to convert the strings in the list to lower case, you can use `map(str.lower, String_Array1)`

Comment: exactly, you have to pass strings to your function, like 'abc'

Comment: `["A"].lower()` won't work because `lower` is a string-function. `["A"][0].lower()` will work on the string.

Comment: @all, thanks. It seems to work when I am looping over my function. Then the error message does not occure...

Comment: @eugenhu, thanks. doing it will not help because the if statement recognize the sting no more and my if-condition fails

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM, thanks. do you have a better suggestion? Since my string array will be more than one item how should it look like?

Comment: @Juergen, thanks but do you have an eyample how it shoul look like?

Comment: Is there a way using numpy arrays perofiming lower cases?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution works with an numpy array using char.lower(). The the if-statement can be performed using any() or all()